# iPad UITableView Scroll bouncing back to top

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableView in a UINavigationview in a UIPopOver control. When the user scrolls the UITableView, the view scrolls back to the top once they let it go. How can I tell the UITableView to stay where it is scrolled to?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put the whole thing into a UIScrollView